# Jquery to show hidden div blocks not showing when the checkboxes are checked

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery function that's supposed to show the div blocks associated with the checkbox is clicked and hidden when the chekcbox in unchecked.
 How do I shows the selected div's associated with the ckecbox when each check is clicked. Curretly when i check  and uncheck its not showing teh hidden div elements

I tried using this

```
 $(this).find(".filterBlock").show();
```

Here is my code and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/qa0dL66x/7/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".filterBlock").hide();
   //fitlers
   $(".checkbox-container :checkbox").click(function() {
       $("div.filterBlock").hide();
       $(".checkbox-container :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
           alert($(this).val());
         //  $(this).show();

           $(this).find(".filterBlock").show();
       });
});


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(".filterBlock").hide();
$(".checkbox-container :checkbox").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').next('.row').find('.filterBlock').toggle()
});
```

[**jsFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/esLdwnc2/)